# Count on the month

Tags: javascript, count, monthcalendar

I have a program which I work with, I use it to add hours of the employees. But now I have a problem, I have set the date automatically on the Monday of past week (28-09-2015 Monday, 29-09-2015 Tuesday etc.), but when I'm at the end of the month, it doesn't work anymore.

Here you can see a picture:

[image]

When we go from 30 September to 1 October, it stopped working.
This is the script I use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function getMonday(d) 
{
var day = d.getDay();
diff = d.getDate() - day + -6; 
return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}

var day = getMonday(new Date());
var month = day.getMonth()+1;

for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
$('[name="start_day'+i+'"').val(day.getDate()+i);
$('[name="start_month'+i+'"').val(month);
}
```

and this is the Javascript I use for the date:

`<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"> </script>`

Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this. Increase the time by 24 hours...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function getMonday(d) 
{
var day = d.getDay();
diff = d.getDate() - day + -6; 
return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}

var day = getMonday(new Date());
var month = day.getMonth()+1;

for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
var thisDate = new Date(day.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * i)); 
$('[name="start_day'+i+'"').val(thisDate.getDate());
$('[name="start_month'+i+'"').val(thisDate.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Hey WhiteHat, thank you very much for your answer! it kinda helped as you can see: http://i57.tinypic.com/r01qbn.png - But the month stays september instead of changing to october, do you maybe know why?

Comment: You should calculate a next date inside the loop and set both calendar values by .val(date.getDate()) and .val(date.getMonth() + 1)

Comment: Hey Max.. How do i do that exactly?

Comment: Thank you guys so so so so much!!!! IT WORKED!!!!!

http://i62.tinypic.com/mrbvgz.png

Im realy happy thank you guys so much i realy apreciate it!!! 
Thank you for all your time!

Comment: cheers! good luck with the rest, glad to help, how 'bout an up vote, or accept an answer?

Comment: I already tried but i get this response when i try to up vote : http://i58.tinypic.com/2zgzvgk.png

When i have 15 points it can be seen.. i would like to give you guys 1000 thumbs up right now :D!!!

Answer (score 0):

Below will work, [fiddler](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mm4cnf55/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function getMonday(d) 
{

var day1 = d.getDay();
diff = d.getDate() - day1 + -6; 
return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}

var day1 = getMonday(new Date());
var month1 = day1.getMonth()+1;

for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    var dat = new Date();
    dat.setDate(day1.getDate() + i);
$('[name="start_day'+i+'"').val(dat);
$('[name="start_month'+i+'"').val(dat.getMonth());
}
});
```

Comment: Hey Sanjay, i tried it, but it doesnt work.. The startday and startmonth became empty..

Comment: my side it is working fine. and only difference is date casting.                  var dat = new Date();
dat.setDate(day1.getDate() + i);

Comment: i think you have tried my code at your side, .text() will not work as i have taken span for showing date and month. please refer fiddler for more details

Comment: Hey sanjay, i realy apreciate your answer, but when i try it on the program it does not work: http://i57.tinypic.com/hrx26o.png

Comment: please remove .text() and place .val() as i think your code uses .val() instead of .text()

Comment: let me change this fix in my code sample above. And please let me know still it is not working

Comment: i've changed the given code sample. Please try it and let me know

Comment: Hey sanjay, i realy tried it, but it only shows the date of today on all 7 rows. The code that WhiteHat posted helped a bit, it only doesnt change the month. I realy dont know what the problem is..

Comment: Hey Sanjay, what do you want me to post exactly..?

Comment: thanks - if i can able to understand i will revert back to you.

Comment: Hey Sanjay, WhiteHat and Max posted the good version.. now it finaly works! But i realy apreciate your time too! Thank you very much for all your time and patience with me!!

Comment: Glad, you got your answer.