# Count on the year

Tags: javascript, count, monthcalendar

I have a question what i already have asked [Count on the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948040/count-on-the-month) and thank god someone helped me good, but now i have another question. The days and months count on automaticaly but when its the end of the year it doesnt work. does anyone know how i can get this to work?

I have set the date automaticaly on the last monday of last week:
This is how it is now

[image]

When i change the date to the end of this year, it stops counting:

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $("#day").change(function () {
                var sDay = parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').val());
                var sMonth = parseInt($(this).next().find('option:selected').val());

                for(var i=0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    var cDay = 'start_day' + i;
                    var cMonth = 'start_month' + i;
                    if(sDay <= 31){
                        $("[name=" + cDay).val(sDay);
                        $("[name=" + cMonth).val(sMonth);
                    }
                    else {
                        sDay = 1;
                        sMonth++;
                        $("[name=" + cDay).val(sDay);
                        $("[name=" + cMonth).val(sMonth);
                    }
                    sDay++;
                }
            });

function getMonday(d) 
            {
                var day = d.getDay();
                diff = d.getDate() - day + -6; 
                return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
            }

            var day = getMonday(new Date());
            var month = day.getMonth()+1;

            for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                var thisDate = new Date(day.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * i)); 
                $('[name="start_day'+i+'"').val(thisDate.getDate());
                $('[name="start_month'+i+'"').val(thisDate.getMonth() + 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var sYear = parseInt($(this).next().next().find('option:selected').val());
for(var i=0; i < 7; i++)
   {
      var date = new Date(sYear, sMonth-1, sDay);
      var cDay = 'start_day' + i;
      var cMonth = 'start_month' + i;
      var cYear = 'start_year' + i;
      $("[name=" + cDay).val(date.getDate());
      $("[name=" + cMonth).val(date.getMonth()+1);
      $("[name=" + cYear).val(date.getFullYear());
      sDay++;
   }
```

Comment: Give me your web-site link. Where i can find this calendars?

Comment: Hey Alex, its not from a website. i use it intern for registering dates and times of employees.

Comment: Ill post my code down below.. why does it not work for me?

Comment: Try to add this line of code: `$('[name="start_year'+i+'"').val(thisDate.getFullYear());`

Comment: after `var thisDate = new Date(day.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * i)); 
                $('[name="start_day'+i+'"').val(thisDate.getDate());
                $('[name="start_month'+i+'"').val(thisDate.getMonth() + 1);`

Comment: Super! Mark question as answered, pls :)

Comment: Hey Alexander, one question please. Since i changed this, its getting very slow? Everytime i want to change date it get stuck for like 5 seconds. Do you know why?

Comment: An example of JSFiddle takes the same amount of time?

Comment: No, thats very fast.. Since the new code it just let me wait like 5 seconds.. it has to load but i dont know why?..

Comment: I dont know why. Maybe some other code creates a problem

Answer (score 0):

Alexander, this is the code i use..

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#day").change(function () {
            var sDay = parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').val());
            var sMonth = parseInt($(this).next().find('option:selected').val());
            var sYear = parseInt($(this).next().next().find('option:selected').val());
            for(var i=0; i < 7; i++)
            {
              var date = new Date(sYear, sMonth-1, sDay);
              var cDay = 'start_day' + i;
              var cMonth = 'start_month' + i;
              var cYear = 'start_year' + i;
              $("[name=" + cDay).val(date.getDate());
              $("[name=" + cMonth).val(date.getMonth()+1);
              $("[name=" + cYear).val(date.getFullYear());
              sDay++;
            }
        });
                $("#day").change();
        });

            function getMonday(d) 
            {
                var day = d.getDay();
                diff = d.getDate() - day + -6; 
                return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
            }

            var day = getMonday(new Date());
            var month = day.getMonth()+1;

            for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                var thisDate = new Date(day.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * i)); 
                $('[name="start_day'+i+'"').val(thisDate.getDate());
                $('[name="start_month'+i+'"').val(thisDate.getMonth() + 1);
            }
```